# SVG: add animate element to a path element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have the following path element in my html:

```
<path fill="#edf1f2" stroke="#ff8d35" d="M236,-8C236,-8 336,-8 336,-8 342,-8 348,-14 348,-20 348,-20 348,-60 348,-60 348,-66 342,-72 336,-72 336,-72 236,-72 236,-72 230,-72 224,-66 224,-60 224,-60 224,-20 224,-20 224,-14 230,-8 236,-8">
</path>
```

Now I want to add programmatically (via Javascript) the following element in the path element:

```
<animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-width" values="6;1;6;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="3"></animate>
```

So the result would look like this:

```
<path fill="#edf1f2" stroke="#ff8d35" d="M236,-8C236,-8 336,-8 336,-8 342,-8 348,-14 348,-20 348,-20 348,-60 348,-60 348,-66 342,-72 336,-72 336,-72 236,-72 236,-72 230,-72 224,-66 224,-60 224,-60 224,-20 224,-20 224,-14 230,-8 236,-8">
<animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-width" values="6;1;6;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="3"></animate></path>
```

How can I accomplish this? I want to do this via Javascript or JQuery, but no external library like D3 lib

**UPDATE**
Here is the code that I have tried with append but it does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1").children("path").append('<animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-width" values="6;1;6;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="3"></animate>')
});
</script>
</head>

<body class="descendants">
  <g id="1">
  <svg width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 320 320">
<path
            id="path1:0" fill="#edf1f2" stroke="#ff8d35"
            d="M160,100 Q200,100,200,300 Q100,300,100,200 Z">
 </svg>
  </g>
</body>
</html>
```

I have just a reference to the `g` element, so I am using `$('#1').children` to find the `path` element.

Comment: just to get this out of the way, do you mean this:`$('path').append('<animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="stroke-width" values="6;1;6;1" dur="2s" repeatCount="3"></animate>');`

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `append` does not add it as a child. Does it?

Comment: yeap, sure does, and `after` adds it as a sibling. One thing, though, I tried it with `$('path#path1:0")` using the `path1:0` id, and *that* way it didn't work, but just `$('path')` worked in my tests

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría I have tried it in my code but it does not work. I have updated my question and inserted what I have implemented. Can you see the problem in my code?

Comment: first: I don't see the ending tag for path: `</path>`, check that out. Second: `.children()` will get you as far as **1** level down the DOM, in other words `.children('path')` is returning `null` because `<path>` is not its *child*, it is its *grandchild* (`<svg>` is the child) so either you use `.find()` which will look for **all** descendants including any other `<path>` it finds down the way or you use `$("#1").children("svg").children("path")` which will get you only the grandchildren, hence the `<path>` you need

Comment: Also I think I tried using just a number as an ID value once and it was kinda quirky, maybe it is nothing, just check that out too

Comment: Yes, thanks that was the bug. I used `children` incorrectly. Just a question: `$("#1")` searches for any element with `id="1"`. Is there a way to use `$` but to search for `g` elements with `id="1"`?

Comment: $("g#1") will give id =1 of g element